# How to check my postgresql function is running or not?

Tags: php, postgresql

I have created

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.officer_view_licences(
    IN lab_code_r character)
  RETURNS TABLE(appl_type_r character varying, appl_date_r timestamp without time zone, shop_name_r character varying, status_r character,  appl_no_r character varying, license_no_r character varying, license_issue_date_r date, issueing_authority_name_r character varying, issueing_authority_desig_r character varying, reject_date_r date, valid_upto_r date) AS
$BODY$
BEGIN
    return QUERY SELECT appl_type, appl_date,  appl_no, license_no, license_issue_date, issueing_authority_name, issueing_authority_desig, reject_date, valid_upto FROM license_detail where lab_code = lab_code_r order by  appl_type, license_issue_date desc ;   
END 
$BODY$
  LANGUAGE plpgsql VOLATILE
  COST 100
  ROWS 1000;
```

function in my database in pgsql and call it from

```
public function officer_view_licences($lab_code){               
        $pgquery = pg_query("select * from officer_view_licences('".$lab_code."')");
        while($row = pg_fetch_assoc($pgquery)) {
            $records[] = $row;                             
        }       
        print_r($records);
        return $records;
    }
```

I have print the records but there is not record print there. but when I run

```
SELECT appl_type, appl_date,  appl_no, license_no, license_issue_date, issueing_authority_name, issueing_authority_desig, reject_date, valid_upto FROM license_detail where lab_code = '119' order by  appl_type, license_issue_date desc ;
```

It will print some record. How could I check that my function is working properly or not?

Comment: which functions do you want to check php function or postgresql function ?.

Comment: postgresql function

Answer (score 0):

You should query `pg_stat_activity`

```
select * from  pg_stat_activity 
 where application_name ~* '[o]fficer_view_licences';
```

Alternatively, you may explicitly give an application name for a session for proper identification

```
set application_name to officer_view_licences_thisone;
```

Then, you may query it like:

```
select * from  pg_stat_activity 
 where application_name = 'officer_view_licences_thisone';
```

Comment: where shoud I put this?

Comment: and how to pass parameter in it?

Comment: @DevarishiPandey : The same way you pass any other parameter in php?

Comment: select * from  pg_stat_activity 
 where application_name = 'officer_view_licences_thisone'; in this code where should I pass $lab_code parameter??

Comment: @DevarishiPandey : I'm not familiar with php, but I think you're making a mistake while passing parameters. You seem to be concatenating them as I can see from your main query. This may lead to [SQL Injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) .You should consider using [pg_query_params](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php)